# Is subjunctive usage justified here?

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive-mood

Context: One (younger one) of the father's sons furtively watches his dad trying to do a mediocre enough back flip but he generally never ever has tried doing it, couple of seconds later his older brother passes by him, so would the first son say the following statement to his big brother when big brother asks him what he is doing?

"Watch our father DO a back flip" (Subjunctive or Infinitive?)

Comment: This is no subjunctive, but simply infinitive...

Comment: I don't  fully believe so, this sentence indicates anticipation/imagining of an event but I'm not 100% sure, hence I need clarification.

Comment: This is an imperative and as such only indicates that the addressee should do what s/he is told to do. No imagining...

Comment: By your logic is the following sentence incorrect in using subjunctive?  "The manager was eager that his visitor SEE the new building."

Comment: Subjunctive requires deletion of verbal "s" with regard to a third person subject. In the case above this holds, but it overlaps with "do" as an infinitive, which is the function of the verb above, in my opinion.

Comment: Read the added context now.

Comment: Once again, imperatives do not co-occur with subjunctives, but maybe you will find someone who sees it differently.

Comment: Subjunctive mood implies a wish of a person, right? So what if the younger son wishes his dad to do a back flip??

Answer (score 1):

> "Watch our father DO a back flip" (Subjunctive or Infinitive?)

Do is an infinitive but the sentence is not idiomatic. (Note the present participle.)

"*[I am] Watch**ing*** father **do** a back flip."

As basic guidance, the verb in answers takes the same form as the verb in the question, and the question was "*big brother asks him what he **is doing**?*